# Pandasai code not running and giving deprecated error

Tags: python

I am trying to run first time the pandasai library.  I have also installed Smartdataframe. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasai import PandasAI
from pandasai.llm.openai import OpenAI
from pandasai import SmartDataframe

llm=OpenAI(api_token="your_API_key")
pandas_ai=PandasAI(llm)
df = pd.read_excel("Clearing.xlsx")

#print(df.shape)
df1 = SmartDataframe(df, config={"llm": llm})
pandas_ai.run(df1,prompt="How many name start with M alphabet")
```

It is giving the following error;

PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\practice\Python>
.1->pandasai) (0.2.2)
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\practice\Python> & C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/practice/Python/PythonAI.py
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandasai_*init*_.py:145: UserWarning: `PandasAI` (class) is deprecated since v1.0 and will be removed in a future release. Please use `SmartDataframe` instead.
warnings.warn(
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\practice\Python> py -m pip --version
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\practice\Python>
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\practice\Python> & C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/practice/Python/PythonAI.py
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandasai_*init*_.py:145: UserWarning: `PandasAI` (class) is deprecated since v1.0 and will be removed in a future release. Please use `SmartDataframe` instead.
warnings.warn(
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\practice\Python> & C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/practice/Python/PythonAI.py

C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandasai_*init*_.py:145: UserWarning: `PandasAI` (class) is deprecated since v1.0 and will be removed in a future release. Please use `SmartDataframe` instead.
warnings.warn(

How can I fix this..

Comment: These are **warnings** about an upcoming breaking change in the library. It is wise to adapt your code ASAP, but they don't prevent the code from running.

Comment: Update Python 3.11.x